# Centering ToggleButton Image - With No Text

Tags: android, button, togglebutton

Here is my `ToggleButton`:

```
<ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/bSmenuTopItems"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/master_button_selector"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/flame_icon" />
```

I have no text in this image, I need a `ToggleButton` due to Active State.

EDIT:  I think question was misunderstood.  There is a drawable inside the Toggle Button (`flame_icon`) and it is set as `background`.  I want it to be *centered*.  There is no Text, just an image.  I need a Toggle Button because I need to have an Active State when selected.

There is only `drawableLeft`, `drawableRight`, `drawableTop`, etc.  I want a `draweableMiddle` that doesn't seem to exisit.

Comment: (1) why weight 50? are there a ton of objectcs in this row that you can't use 1 for each to represent equal weight? (2) what kind of layout? have you tried layout_gravity instead of just gravity? or center_horizontal if its a relative layout?

Comment: @Rarw  It's a `LinearLayout`.  But why would that affect what goes on inside the `button`?

Comment: I thought you were centering the button. You're trying to center the image in the button?

Comment: @Rarw  yes, that is exactly what I am trying.  padding seems to be the only option for drawable

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I revised the answer to answer your revised question.

The `drawableLeft`, `drawableRight`, and `drawableTop` button, as far as I can tell, control where the image is placed relative to the selector (a/k/a on/off) indicator. Top will place it above the indicator with left and right placing it to a specific side respectively. I do not believe you can remove the selector indicator as that would defeat the purpose of using a `ToggleButton`.

I was able to center 2 drawable in 2 `ToggleButtons` using the following layout. To center the images within the `ToggleButton` I used `drawableTop` so that the images appeared over the selection indicator. I then set both `textOn` and `textOff` to be an empty string. If you do not set this, then the default on/off text appears above the selector indicator and pushes the drawable to the side.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/buttonContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"> 

   <ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/bSmenuTopItems"
        android:layout_width="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/flag"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#cecece" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/bSmenuTopItems2"
        android:layout_width="0"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/chaticon"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#cecece" />

</LinearLayout>
```

All you should have to do is adjust the height of the button to position your icon relative to the selector icon where you want it. My only other suggestion would be to control the size of the image you are  using. If you can just adjust the dimensions of the image relative to the button, placing it with drawableTop should center it automatically.

Comment: Sorry, I think question was misunderstood.  I have updated it.

Comment: Revised answer to match question

Comment: @Rarw I'm trying to do the same thing atm, so there is no method to place the image in the center of the button without resizing the image? I'd be worried about how it would appear on multiple devices manually resizing it (is that a valid concern?).

Comment: @DanielImms I was able to center the image in the buttons using what I described above. There is no `drawableCenter` XML attribute I believe because the positioning relates to toggle/selection indicator in the button. You could adjuste the image used based on the size of the screen if you were concerned about method 2. My third suggestion is just to use a regular button, change the background color or image `onClick` to indicate a highlighted state, and sort of create your own toggle button without using the built in form.

Comment: @Rarw I ended up centering it using `drawablePadding`.

Answer (score 10):

I didn't have any luck with the accepted answer but maybe my scenario is subtly different.  The other solution I've seen is to use the drawablePadding attribute to push the topDrawable toward the center of the button. That works to an extent but it assumes that the button's dimensions are fixed and even then, it's difficult to center the icon perfectly.

**This is what I came up with instead.**  Don't specify the icon on the button itself.  Instead, set the button's background to a layer-list drawable that draws the icon you want over the selector you want, like so:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/master_button_selector" />
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/flame_icon" android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Works like a charm... not sure why I didn't think about this as a solution before.

Comment: I wonder how this would work when needing to show different states?

Comment: @ClumsyHamster If you're _actually_ curious, you could always try it instead of wondering aloud on StackOverflow. ;) It works great. Notice that the first `<item>` is a selector. The button's state changes propagate down to it.

Answer (score 0):

I used the `android:drawableTop` as described by Rarw, but as my button was tall and wide, it just hung at the top. Not really centred...so I fiddled around with the `paddingTop` and it might work here what I got:

```
   <ToggleButton 
    android:id="@+id/togglebutton1"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/music_collection_small"
    android:textOn=""
    android:textOff=""

    />
```

I think it will work for my purposes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598255/android-create-a-toggle-button-with-image-and-no-text) will help you. Look at the bottom of the page for the solution from 
zapl. 
P.S didn't know how to link the specific answer, new here XD

Comment: FYI, this isn't really an answer (at least not a quality one). Please post as a comment once you have enough rep to do so.